# Looking for an apple recognized itunes

Tags: itunes

I do a lot with my iPhone and iTunes. My question is simple, is there a way to get an Apple recognized version of iTunes for Ubuntu?

Comment: I would ask Apple, since Ubuntu is an Open Source OS there is nothing that keeps them from developing on it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no iTunes for Ubuntu. You can try [gtkPod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Home) (if your iPod/iPhone is supported) or you can install Windows in a virtual machine just for iTunes.